# Linux Device Driver interfacing

Tags: linux, driver, device

In device driver programming we are using following items:

```
1. Device driver code
2. Device file
3. Actual physical Hardware (till now not used in my coding)
4. User space application code
```

What I understood is device file is a intermediate bridge between device driver code and user application code. And device file is a temporary (like bidirectional pipe) buffer.

Can anybody clarify me whatever I understood is correct?  Also explain me how above four listed things are communicated internally in kernel. Even tried from LDD3 book, but still I am not getting correct picture.

Comment: You might be better off posting in https://unix.stackexchange.com/ , the Unix & Linux area.

Comment: @Kixoka, Thanks for your reply and I will post this question in unix.stackexcanhe.com, But I want to know what type of questions can I ask in stackoverflow.com and most of the questions i am posting here is getting lower reputation.

Comment: Hopefully this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the question in context of linux.

1. Device driver code:
   Device driver is a interface between linux kernel and device driver.
   There are many things defined notably `ioctls`, and other device
   management
2. Device file:
   Everything in linux is a file. Kernel assumes device is also a file. you
   can find devices in `/dev`
3. Actual physical Hardware (till now not used in my coding)
   Hardware device contains its firmware code.
4. User space application code
   User application exists in user space and it communicates with device
   driver using `ioctls`.